# Home surveillance software that can handle multiple USB cameras

Tags: windows, usb, webcam

I'm looking for a home surveillance software for Windows that supports multiple USB cameras that are *not* connected to the same computer.

I tried iSpy which supports this through installing a streaming server on the remote machine, but I found this software far too complicated and cumbersome (in regards to both setup and usage).

Requirements:

1. As mentioned, support multiple USB cameras not connected to the same machine.
2. Relatively simple and friendly UX.
3. Motion detection (sound detection - a plus).
4. Preferably free or low cost (but it's not mandatory).

My host machine runs Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview, but I can also run it on my Windows 7 machine.